# collide_widget with negative size

Tags: python, kivy

I'm having a few widgets and want to "drag and select" them. I use a selection widget as rectangle to show selection size and then use `for child in root.children: selection.collide_widget(child)`. This works great aslong as I drag from left-bottom to right-top direction because the selection widgets size will then be positive.

Is it expected that widgets with negative size will not work with collide_widget?

Should I not use negative sizes for widgets at all?

kv file:

```
<SelectionBox>:
    size: 0,0
    size_hint: None, None
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 0.1
        Rectangle:
            pos: root.pos
            size: root.size

<Selectable>:
    size: 32, 32
    size_hint: None, None
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 0, 1, 0, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: root.pos
            size: root.size
```

code:

```
class Selectable(Widget):
    pass

class Canvas(FloatLayout):

    touch_down = False

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        self.selection = sel = SelectionBox()
        sel.pos = touch.pos
    self.touch_down = True
        self.add_widget(sel)

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        if self.touch_down:
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Interesting line here ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            # size can get negative 
            self.selection.size = (touch.pos[0] - self.selection.pos[0] , touch.pos[1] - self.selection.pos[1])

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):

        for widget in self.children:
            if widget is self.selection:
                print("Children is selection")
            if self.selection.collide_widget(widget):
            print("Widget collides: {}".format(widget))

        self.touch_down = False
        self.remove_widget(self.selection)

canvas = Canvas()

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        canvas = Canvas()
    for i in range(0,11):
        sel = Selectable()
        sel.pos = random.random() * 1000, random.random() * 1000
        self.add_widget(sel)
        return canvas

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, this behaviour is expected. From `kivy.uix.widget.Widget`:

```
def collide_widget(self, wid):
    if self.right < wid.x:
        return False
    if self.x > wid.right:
        return False
    if self.top < wid.y:
        return False
    if self.y > wid.top:
        return False
    return True
```

For a negative size, this logic will not work, as e.g. `self.right < self.x`. An easy workaround would be to redefine `collide_widget` for those classes where negative sizes are expected:

```
def collide_widget(self, wid):    
    if max(self.x, self.right) < min(wid.x, wid.right):
        return False
    if min(self.x, self.right) > max(wid.x, wid.right):
        return False
    if max(self.top, self.y) < min(wid.y, wid.top):
        return False
    if min(self.top, self.y) > max(wid.y, wid.top):
        return False
    return True
```

This takes care of both widgets (the one calling `collide_widget` and the one being tested) having positive or negative sizes.

I'm not sure, however, if code somewhere else relies on negative sizes not colliding as expected (so monkey-patch onto `Widget` with care).